# Problems aligning object to far right : HTML & CSS

Tags: css, html

**Basically  I have an email logo on my page and I want the logo to go the far right, if i go onto the javascript console and toggle through tthe devices(chrome) I't shows alot of white space ; which isn't good. How would I get my logo to the far-right of the screen.**

Thanks

Comment: #email_logo{
            position:absolute;
   top:130px;
   widt:170px;
   height:170px;
   left:300px;
   }

Comment: change the top and left values

Comment: doing that would widen my screen and I don't want that

Comment: Can you display us ur codes please

Comment: @JeffreyKolaAbodunde Is it an mailer template based on `<table>` ?

Comment: Please provide essential parts of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
#email_logo_container{position: relative;}

#email_logo{ position:absolute; top:130px; width:170px; height:170px; right:0; }
```

If you could provide a screenshot of what exactly you need would help us to answer you more clearly and accurately. Cheers!!